# php SoapClient request with string parameter that contains XML is getting encoded

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

I have a php script that is interacting with a .NET web service. I have multiple pieces that are calling different functions via soap with no issue so everything is working great.

PHP Version => 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.18

My new situation is a specific function that requires 4 parameters, all of type string, but one of which is an entire XML document.

When I look at the request I'm sending for this function, everything in the request looks great except the xml, which is encoded (all the opening and closing brackets).

It seems like there should be a strait forward way to deal with this but nothing is coming up on the net. I have tried SoapClient options and escaping but nothing is changing this.

Here is the XML being fed to the SoapClient:

```
<Setup>
  <CustomerAccount>xxxx24838</CustomerAccount>
  <MasterSource enumType="MasterSource">3</MasterSource>
  <MasterReceived enumType="YesNo">1</MasterReceived>
  <AID>kjsdlkfjsldkfj334</AID>
</Setup>
```

Here is the request being sent:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.xxxxxxx.com/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:Save>
      <ns1:objectName>CASetup</ns1:objectName>
      <ns1:xmlData>
        &lt;Setup&gt;&lt;CustomerAccount&gt;xxxx24838&lt;/CustomerAccount&gt;
        &lt;MasterSource enumType="MasterSource"&gt;3&lt;/MasterSource&gt;
        &lt;MasterReceived enumType="YesNo"&gt;1&lt;/MasterReceived&gt;
        &lt;AID&gt;kjsdlkfjsldkfj334&lt;/AID&gt;
        &lt;/Setup&gt;
      </ns1:xmlData>
      <ns1:operation>saveMasterAsReceived</ns1:operation>
      <ns1:Brand>6</ns1:Brand>
    </ns1:Save>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I have formatted just for ease of reading.

Comment: Looks like this is likely a non issue at least in my situation as I was finally able to confirm that the child XML doc in the soap request IS being decoded just fine on the server side. Something else is likely the issue!

Comment: Sounds so because as a string it even must be encoded otherwise this wouldn't work and you would loose data.